# Include Java files like PHP's include

Tags: java, include

Is there a way to import a .java file in another .java file like PHP's `include`?
When using PHP, it imports the entire included page, including functions, variables etc. So basically it should like copy-paste the other file's source in the main file.

I have a pretty big Java file right now, and it's getting kinda unorganized.

Comment: If yours java file is too big you're doing something wrong :). You will have to figure out how to reorganize youre code in classes that can be imported into original java file!

Comment: It works, but it's unorganized, I have to scroll a lot everytime I'm editing it, and this takes some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep! It's called `import`.

It will look something like this:

```
package com.somename.someabstraction;

import com.somename.someabstraction.somepackage;


public class MyClass {

//...
```

You will not be able to mimic the `include` function of PHP because Java is not served "on-the-fly" like PHP, JSP or JS.

Further, Java code by convention is broken down into more meaningful abstractions through the use of classes, packages and import statements.

Comment: I think there's a difference between the import and the include. The include is like copy-pasting the source PHP file into another PHP file. A Java import by itself does nothing. You can import all the Java packages without any effect in the class.

Comment: CydrickT, that's what I mean. I want to like copy-paste the source from the other file in the main one.

Comment: @iJeroen I know, and that's why this answer is not the same as a PHP include.

Comment: @CydrickT yes that is true, but essentially this is the same thing because like jsp:include those calls are on the fly server side. Java source code must be compiled and then those linked .class files with the `import` statement are called with various methods etc.

Comment: @iJeroen you're not going to find anything like php's include for java because java code is not served 'on-the-fly' like PHP, JS or JSP. Import is going to be your best alternative. Any time someone has a 'pretty big java file' they most likely need to refactor into smaller, more meaningful abstractions

Comment: @andrewdleach I agree with a part of the second comment. There's nothing like an include in Java. Split the content of the file into multiple classes, and use these classes inside your main class. The include is only a part of the solution.

Comment: @andrewdleach Okay, thanks for that, but I'm quite a noob with classes and import, so could you explain it a little bit more? Like, how to use a variable from the other class?

Comment: @andrewdleach Got it! Made another class named Variables, put it in the same package named "main". Now I used import main.Variables; and imported the variable bij Variables.awesomeVariable; <br> Thanks for helping out, appreciated

Comment: @iJeroen you're welcome. If my post answered your question please mark as resolved for other devs who come across your original question.